# Azure Cosmos DB Date Query as string not working

Tags: c#, datetime, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Basically its just query get operation in azure cosmos db based on machine id and datetime.
I am really stuck on querying in cosmos based on datetime.The same query I am able to run and get the result on azure portal.But code wise I am not getting the result.

A few more details:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM c
WHERE c.IoTHub.ConnectionDeviceId IN ('hub20') AND c.MACHINE_ID = 'TAP_20' AND (c.EventEnqueuedUtcTime >= '2021-02-03T10:40:42.5180000Z' AND c.EventEnqueuedUtcTime <= '2021-02-03T10:40:42.5180000Z')
```

```cs
QueryDefinition queryDefinition = new QueryDefinition(sqlQueryText);
FeedIterator<dynamic> queryResultSetIterator = container.GetItemQueryIterator<dynamic>(queryDefinition);
FeedResponse<dynamic> currentResultSet;
while (queryResultSetIterator.HasMoreResults)
{
    currentResultSet = await queryResultSetIterator.ReadNextAsync();
}
```

I am able to get all the data till MACHINE_ID but as soon as I apply c.EventEnqueuedUtcTime condition. I am not able to get the data.I tried every possible solution.c.EventEnqueuedUtcTime value we are getting as a string and also in database it is saved as string as you can see in the image.

```json
{
    "MESSAGE_GROUP_ID": "24c9e3ad-4fd6-4abb-88d8-eafb9060884e",
    "TYPE": "Gauges",
    "MACHINE_ID": "TAP_20",
    "Gauges": {
        "OVERRIDE": 85.8
    },
    "EventProcessedUtcTime": "2021-02-03T10:41:48.0493615Z",
    "PartitionId": 3,
    "EventEnqueuedUtcTime": "2021-02-03T10:40:42.5180000Z",
    "IoTHub": {
        "MessageId": "498b7df3-55e6-4b3f-a18e-698fd991e526",
        "CorrelationId": null,
        "ConnectionDeviceId": "hub20",
        "ConnectionDeviceGenerationId": "637332663098221999",
        "EnqueuedTime": "2021-02-03T10:41:11.2570000Z"
    },
    "id": "498b7df3-55e6-4b3f-a18e-698fd991e526"
}
```

[image]

Any lead will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: Two things I noticed: 1) From and to date/time value in your query are the same so effectively you are looking for a record with `EventEnqueuedUtcTime` value equal to `2021-02-03T10:40:42.5180000Z` and 2) Looking at the data screenshot, the value in the database lies outside of the date/time value you're searching for.

Comment: 1. Yes, You are right I am looking for a value right now.
2. Second point is not clear, What do you mean by database lies outside.EventEnqueuedUtcTime I am looking for which is saved as default format of datetime as string.

Comment: Please edit your question to include properly-formatted text for your document example, not an image of text. This [meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/272109) lists many reasons why this is very important.

Comment: I have edited the question and added the text. I am not sure why it is not working but if querying till machine my query is working fine as soon as I include EventEnqueuedUtcTime it does not give result . Means my count becomes 0 actually i should get 1 result.

Comment: The value in the query is `2021-02-03T10:40:42.5180000Z` however the value in the database is `2021-02-03T10:41:11.3190000Z`.

Comment: Sorry, it was just typing mistake still the result is same.

Comment: Is any update on that why it is not able to compare similar strings.

Comment: Thanks to everyone. I was saving it incorrectly using casting now I am getting the correct result. I marked it as solved.

Comment: Please don't mark a question as solved by editing the title, instead create an answer on how the problem was solved

Answer (score 0):

Thank you [user2911592](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2911592/user2911592) for sharing the resolution steps. Posting them as answer to help other community members.

> Initially the query/code was saved incorrectly using casting. Fixing
> the same resolved the issue.

[user2911592](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2911592/user2911592): feel free to add furthermore details.